# How to notify any change from One database to another database

Tags: mysql, database, triggers, db2

Is it possible to notify a database from another database, both the database are on different server. and both the database are different type. eg. if i have a DB2 database on one server and some records are updated on this database than  need to notify another DB and modify some table in on that DB(my case it is MYSql).

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can create a link between databases and using triggers - update corresponding data in the other database.

Comment: Parkyprg, Thanks a lot for your suggestion, in your approch i think we need to create all the types of triggers on each and every Tables. which will be really a cumbersome and in many cases it is possible that enterprise db owner dont allow us to add Triggers on their DB.

Comment: Adding triggers to a table will be time-consuming while working with the table. As an alternative, you can make a script that will run at a specific interval and track all the changes and update corresponding data. This will need more work to be done in the beginning.

Comment: Yes i think it would be better approach. i dont have any idea about scripts which work with DB.. need to understand it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would investigate replication, to see if mySQL can be a replication target for DB2.

Read [introduction to SQL Replication](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.ii.db2udb.replication.intro.doc/prod_overview/iiyrcintrssql.html).